# Approach to exec SUM() but always rounding UP to the nearest penny for individual records

Tags: php, mysql

**Background / What am I dealing with:**

A table with a 'cost' field, a money value.

I'm aware money should be dealt with just 2 decimal places but it is essential as the customers may buy in bulk and it may be 0.0000287 per item.

Now, when the ***billing part*** comes, 'cost' always rounded up no matter, to the nearest penny. E.g 0.0000222 -> 0.01

Each bill may contain hundrends to thousands of items.

**What I want to do**

Execute a SUM() query on the cost field to get the total cost of bill while still rounding up individual records.

```
Item Name         Cost
   A              $0.000000022      // (The DB engine will round it to $0.02 but I want it to be $0.03)
Item Name         Cost
   B              $0.020000000      // left alone $0.02
Item Name         Cost
   C              $0.080000000     // left alone $0.08
Item Name         Cost
   D              $0.092000000     // becomes $0.10
```

Total would be: $0.21... but with the SUM() it would give me $0.18.

**What I tried to do**

1) Create a new column called 'cost_**ru**' that is already **r**ounded **u**p whenever a new record is inserted into the DB.

I don't like the method of a new column because it is esstentially a duplicate data and it would be far better to use a SQL query that does the job. + What if we agreed with a client to a different precision value?

2) Insert the full-value of cost (20~ decimal places) and use a round-up function at real-time when  the bill is being generated.

I realize this isn't a scalable solution because I really don't want to execute functions in the 'view' file.

Comment: why should $0.000000027 become 0.03?

Comment: @e4c5 It is how the business is done.

Comment: @Spylot, I changed the 0.03 to 0.01 for clarity

Comment: @Cœur Nah, that edit defeats the purpose of 'what I want to do' part. I need it to be rounded UP.

Comment: **0.000000022** rounded up is 0.01. Some users are voting to close the question because of the unclear maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the MySQL `CEILING` function, on the result from cost times 100.  Then divide by 100. And then perform the aggregation on the return from that expression.

```
  SUM(CEILING( t.cost *100.0)/100.0)
```

Or, do the division after the aggregation

```
  SUM(CEILING( t.cost *100.0))/100.0
```

(This assumes datatype of `cost` column is `DECIMAL`. If datatype is of `cost` column is floating point type, it might be necessary to perform an explicit conversion (`CONVERT` or `CAST`) to `DECIMAL`.)

As far as performance, I don't think the evaluation of the expression will make any measurable difference in execution time.

Reference:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling